# Python how to take screenshots of higher resolution

Tags: python, scripting, screencast

It's known you can take a screenshot of a particular blender window using something like this
    bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(
        filepath=filepath,
        check_existing=False)

But how can I take a screenshot of a higher resolution? For example how can I get a non pixelated screenshot of the 3D viewport (assuming there are no textures), in 1920/1080 resolution? Is there some kind of option for this?

Blender python 2.79 or 2.8 is fine, I just want to know how to do this

Comment: Never used it but have a look here: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#rendering-the-3d-view-into-a-texture

Comment: @lemon still doesn't explain how to change resolution unfortunetely